# Jquery even after including in the header doesnt get detected

Tags: jquery, html, spring, web

I am using ftl file for my front end . I have included jquery in my head as

```
<script src="/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

i tried to run this script in my body

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    alert('working');

});

</script>
```

Its not working and i get an error like this in my firefox console as "ReferenceError: $ is not defined ".Can anyone help me out with this.

Comment: What is your Directory structure???

Comment: Try adding type="text/javascript" in the script tag

Comment: my directory structure is webapp/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js

Comment: Try using the jquery CDN.

Comment: I think that adding `type="text/javascript"` won't help as it's the default

Answer (score 1):

Your code to include js file should be like:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

There is no need of first "/"?

Answer (score 1):

Seem like the path to your jQuery file is not correct, try to use:

```
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

or better using CDN:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you put your jQuery code after you've included jQuery core file?

Comment: ya.Actually my view file is in webapp->WEB-INF -> view folder and my js file is in webapp->js->jquery-2.0.3.min.js . When i use the CDN it works but i need my jqiery file to be included

Answer (score 0):

That script tag works or not depending on which page you are in your folder structure. Start adding the full path like this but with your urls:

`<script src="http://localhost:8080/myApp/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>`

And see if this work. If it does it means that your path was wrong. If that works you can change the src to be:

`src='/myApp/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'`